# Removing list of strings from column in pandas

Tags: python, pandas

I would need to remove a list of strings:

```
list_strings=['describe','include','any']
```

from a column in pandas:

```
My_Column

include details about your goal
describe expected and actual results
show some code anywhere
```

I tried

```
df['My_Column']=df['My_Column'].str.replace('|'.join(list_strings), '')
```

but it removes parts of words.

For example:

```
My_Column

details about your goal
expected and actual results
show some code where # here it should be anywhere
```

My expected output:

```
My_Column

details about your goal
expected and actual results
show some code anywhere
```

Comment: The result makes sense given that you ask pandas to remove the string "any" when it finds it. If you want any word that starts with "any", then you might want to do a regex like `"any[a-z]*"`

Comment: I would like to remove words that are in the list, so only any, not anywhere. I am new, so probably I made a mistake in my code

Comment: Oh I see, I misunderstood. I'll make a post

Comment: You are removing words that does not exist. Describe -> describe? Format string first

Comment: @MarianD: I feel like you barely read the post and your answer doesn't solve it. He wants to remove the words in his list, but his problem is that some of the words are prefixes of other words, which he doesn't want to remove

Comment: @Nakor, you are right, thanks, I corrected my answer. By the way, your comment was useful, while your downvoting provided no info — neither for me, nor for others. Please consider preferring comments to downvoting in the future.

Comment: @MarianD: The purpose of downvoting is to provide one main info: the answer is not not solving the question (or has some bad side-effects). So it did provide that info. I didn't comment because there was already a correct answer and I assumed that you would read the other answers to understand the problem with your post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the "word boundary" expression `\b` like.

```
In [46]: df.My_Column.str.replace(r'\b{}\b'.format('|'.join(list_strings)), '')
Out[46]: 
0         details about your goal
1     expected and actual results
2         show some code anywhere
Name: My_Column, dtype: object
```

Comment: wow, didn't know this word boundary option, that's super handy

Answer (score 0):

The first parameter of `.str.replace()` method must be a string or compiled regex; not a list as you have.

You probably wanted

```
list_strings=['Describe','Include','any']            # Note capital D and capital I

for s in [f"\\b{s}\\b" for s in list_strings]:       # surrounded word boundaries (\b) 
    df['My_Column'] = df['My_Column'].str.replace(s, '')
```

to obtain

> ```
>                      My_Column
> 0      details about your goal
> 1  expected and actual results
> 2      Show some code anywhere
> ```

Comment: Hi MarianD, thank you for your help. What I would like is removing from My_Column only words that are in the list. So only any, not anywhere. Thanks for the spot in capital letters!

Comment: I added the `regex=False` parameter to obtain the appropriate result - see my edited answer.

Comment: Thanks MarianD. Unfortunately it is still not working

Comment: @user105599, I corrected my answer — I hope now it is OK.

Answer (score 0):

Your issue is that `pandas` doesn't see words, it simply sees a list of characters. So when you ask pandas to remove "any", it doesn't start by delineating words. So one option would be to do that yourself, maybe something like this:

```py
# Your data
df = pd.DataFrame({'My_Column':
['Include details about your goal',
'Describe expected and actual results',
'Show some code anywhere']})

list_strings=['describe','include','any'] # make sure it's lower case

def remove_words(s):
    if s is not None:
        return ' '.join(x for x in s.split() if x.lower() not in list_strings)

# Apply the function to your column
df.My_Column = df.My_Column.map(remove_words)
```

Comment: I get this error: AttributeError: 'float' object has no attribute 'split'

Comment: I guess you have missing values in your DataFrame? I fixed the code to handle that case. But anyway, I think you should go with Zero answer, it's probably faster and more "pythonic"